# IMapisession::OpenMsgStore fails while accessing archive mailbox by using an account having full access permission in Exchange Online (O365)

Tags: exchange-server, office365, mapi

I am trying to access archive mailbox using an account which has full access permissions on the mailbox. The mailbox and archive both are in cloud - O365. I have "ArchiveGUID" of the archive which I want to access. I use this ArchiveGUID and append to MsgStoreEntryID.

For example, I want to access xyz's mailbox archive (present in O365) using account "SuperAccnt". SuperAccnt has full access permission on xyz's mailbox. I have archive GUID of xyz's mailbox. IMapiSession::OpenMsgStore fails here. With full access permissions I am able to access xyz' mailbox and dumpster. It just fails while accessing archive mailbox.

Do we require any other permissions given to SuperAccnt on xyz's mailbox archive so that it is accessible using SuperAccnt?

One thing I tried to execute the same code using xyz's account i.e. access xyz's mailbox archive using its own account and I was successful. Does this mean that we need some explicit permission given to access archive mailbox apart from full access permission.

Thanks in advance,

Pranay

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Outlook or Exchange MAPI?  If Outlook, what version of Outlook?  Outlook 2013 will default to using MAPI over HTTP to connect to Exchange Online, and, for whatever reason, opening secondary mailboxes on Exchange Online fails with that protocol.  Also, the OPENSTORE_USE_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE flag doesn't work with Exchange Online and must be omitted.

Comment: I am using Outlook MAPI. Outlook version 2013. One strange thing I observed here is that if I open the same outlook profile using Outlook and let archive store load in Outlook, then close Outlook and then try to call OpenMsgStore. This way call to OpenMsgStore succeeds.
So it is like if I want to access archive mailbox, I need to open profile once in Outlook and close. Then all the call to OpenMsgStore succeed.
Any idea about this strange behavior ?